# FastCGI+lighttpd+C++: How can I access the HTTP headers in code?

Tags: http-headers, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm developing `RESTFul` APIs by FastCGI in C/C++, deploying in `Lighttpd`, in a embedded system. I want to use Basic Authorization. The official approach is to configure it in `lighttpd.conf` with files that contains usr+password.

But my embedded system has its own user management system, it is hard to merge aforementioned  static user+password mechanism. So I was wondering if I can access the HTTP Header like `"Authorization: Basic SGVsbWVyxxxxxx3b3JkMDE="` in my code, and do the verification of user+pass by myself.

The PROBLEM: I found I can get the headers information for `"CONTENT_LENGTH"`, `"REQUEST_URI"`, `"REQUEST_METHOD"`, etc. by calling `getenv()`, but no environment variables for `"Authorization"`. How can I get this `HTTP header` in my code?

Thanks,
Isaac Wang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lighttpd mod_fastcgi with FastCGI "mode" => "authorizer"

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI

lighttpd does not pass the Authorization header when FastCGI "mode" => "responder" (the default).

.

The following is FALSE:

> The official approach is to configure it in lighttpd.conf with files that contains usr+password.

That is INCORRECT.  lighttpd supports more than a few authn options besides files, such as GSSAPI, LDAP, MySQL, PAM, and SASL, and lighttpd has a reusable framework if you wanted to write a custom mod_authn_* module.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAuth

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and answers gstrauss! You are right that some of my description is not so accurate. I just didn't want to use those mechanism, like MySQL, etc. because it is so heavy to my system. My real requirement is how to get the HTTP headers. <br>Fortunately I found the solution after I took a quick glance at the source code of lighttpd, found the rule to transmit headers to env vars - make the header key to upper case first, then add prefix "HTTP_". In another word, I can get a header "SomeHeader" by getenv("HTTP_SOMEHEADER").

Comment: The variables are defined in RFC 3875.  See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4.1 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4.1.18